# How to expect fatal errors with simpletest in php

Tags: php, simpletest

I am attempting to write a test case to ensure a Singleton class cannot be instantiated. The constructor for the Singleton is defined to be private so my test is as follows:

```
$this->expectError();
$test = new TestSingletonClassA();
```

Instead of catching the error and passing the test, I get a 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to private Singleton::__construct()'. I've also tried passing a PatternExpectation as a parameter to expectError, but that didn't work either. Do you have any suggestions?

Some background: php5.3, simpletest1.1a

Answer (score 0):

If your php code throws a FATAL ERROR, it will never get to the phpunit, so you have to write "right" code in order to test it. If you call a private method, it will throw an excepcion, so it won't get to the phpunit. You have to change that.

I think you have to mock the object. Try [these posts](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html) about this subject (it's a series of 4 posts) and [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/sebastian_bergmann/phpunit-best-practices) (from slide #43) .

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing frameworks cannot catch such things. But you can with [PHPT](http://qa.php.net/phpt_details.php) and similar regression test frameworks.

You might have to jump through some hoops to hook it into PHPUnit, but there's probably ways to integrate it with the remaining tests. You'll just have to separate assertions and the special case where you expect the fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

i don't think it's possible to do it that way.. fatal errors are not catchable as i've understood it. you could use reflection to get the constructor method, and then make sure it has the access modifier "private".

this is hard to test in most languages. for example java, c# and c++ would not even let you compile this code. so it could never be run at all D:

Comment: So I guess for this situation, instead of test cases I should focus on correct design? In my implementation, Singleton is an abstract class, so I want some way to ensure subclasses cannot implement a public constructor, but can override the private constructor. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: i don't think so.. but there are other ways of making sure that the constructor isn't being called when it shouldn't. one way would be having an array keeping track of instantiated classes. another would be using debug_stacktrace to check that the call stack comes from within some get_instance method. both strategies would be applied inside the constructor of the base class. also, i think you need to make your base class constructor protected, or subclass constructor will probably not be able to call parent::__construct